# Capturing click event on combination of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, checkbox

For example, I have 3 checkboxes.  I want to trigger different events bases on combinations of boxes being checked.  For instance, I want an click event triggered on clicking checkbox 1 and a different event based on clicking **both checkbox 1 and checkbox 2**.

**REVISED CODE:**

```
        var tSalesPro = document.getElementById("chkSalesPro");
        var tSalesProPlus = document.getElementById("chkSalesProPlus");
        var tTellerPro = document.getElementById("chkTellerPro");

        function checkBoxChecked() {

            if (tSalesPro.checked && tSalesProPlus.checked && tTellerPro.checked) {
                alert("checkboxes all checked");
            }
            else if (tSalesPro.checked && tSalesProPlus.checked) {
                alert("checkbox 1 & 2 checked");
            }
            else if (tSalesProPlus.checked && tTellerPro.checked) {
                alert("checkbox 2 & 3 checked");
                tSalesProPlus.show();
                tSalesPro.hide();
                tTellerPro.hide();
                tSalesProPlus.checked = false;
                tTellerPro.checked = false;
            }
            else if (tSalesPro.checked && tTellerPro.checked) {
                alert("checkbox 1 & 3 checked");
                tSalesPro.show();
                tSalesPro.hide();
                tSalesProPlus();
                tSalesPro.checked = false;
                tSalesProPlus.checked = false;
            }
            else if (tSalesPro.checked) {
                alert("checkbox 1 checked");
                tSalesPro.show();
                tSalesProPlus.hide();
                tTellerPro.hide();
                tSalesProPlus.checked = false;
                tTellerPro.checked = false;
            }
            else if (tSalesProPlus.checked) {
                alert("checkbox 2 checked");
                tSalesProPlus.show();
                tSalesPro.hide();
                tTellerPro.hide()
                tSalesPro.checked = false;
                tTellerPro.checked = false;
            }
            else if (tTellerPro.checked) {
                alert("checkbox 3 checked");
                tTellerPro.show();
                tSalesPro.hide();
                tSalesProPlus();
                tSalesPro.checked = false;
                tSalesProPlus.checked = false;
            }
        }

        tSalesPro.onclick = checkBoxChecked;
        tSalesProPlus.onclick = checkBoxChecked;
        tTellerPro.onclick = checkBoxChecked;
```

Comment: Have you tried to check which checkboxes are checked each time you click one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a simple example of showing how to use javascript and onclick events in order to determine which checkboxes are checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkSalesPro">
<input type="checkbox" id="chkSalesProPlus">
<input type="checkbox" id="chkTellerPro">


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

     function checkBoxChecked() {
       var tSalesPro = $("#chkSalesPro");
       var tSalesProPlus = $("#chkSalesProPlus");
       var tTellerPro = $("#chkTellerPro");

       if (tSalesPro[0].checked && tSalesProPlus[0].checked && tTellerPro[0].checked) {
           alert("checkboxes all checked");
       }
       else if (tSalesPro[0].checked && tSalesProPlus[0].checked) {
           alert("checkbox 1 & 2 checked");
       } 
       else if (tSalesProPlus[0].checked && tTellerPro[0].checked) {
           alert("checkbox 2 & 3 checked");
       }
       else if (tSalesPro[0].checked && tTellerPro[0].checked) {
           alert("checkbox 1 & 3 checked");
       }
       else if (tSalesPro[0].checked) {
           alert("checkbox 1 checked");
       }
       else if (tSalesProPlus[0].checked) {
           alert("checkbox 2 checked");
       }
       else if (tTellerPro[0].checked) {
           alert("checkbox 3 checked");
       }
   };
   $("#chkSalesPro, #chkSalesProPlus, #chkTellerPro").change(checkBoxChecked);
});
</script>
```

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/T8YMh/5/

Comment: @Susan  was my solution any help to you?

Comment: sort of ... still having a problem.  The actions I have pasted in the conditional clauses aren't firing.  Each condition causes a drop-down box to be visible and the others not to be visible.  I will post the cose above in my original post. ~susan~

Comment: @Susan are you using jQuery?   also can I see your HTML Markup to provide a more complete answer

Comment: Yes, I am using jQuery mixed with JavaScript.  The data is coded in an XML document using deserializing XML to create the form (asp.net MVC).

Comment: @Susan... I have modified the code to more closely align to what you are trying to do, in addition I modified the code to use jQuery for selecting elements and binding the change event.  I omitted the show and hide calls to try to simplify the issue.  Notice at the bottom I provided a working example.  Let me know if there is anything else I can help with.

Comment: Hey John -- thanks, this works great.  I'm so new to scripting, I really appreciate your help.  ~susan~

Comment: @Susan...Not a problem at all...glad I could help out.  Just remember in the future, the more detail you provide in your question the better and more precise the answer will be.

Answer (score 0):

You can't click two boxes at the same time.  I would set the onclick event to be the same for all of the check boxes you're interested in, and in that function, inspect which boxes have been checked and do the appropriate processing based on that combination you find.

Answer (score 0):

may be you want to perform different tasks depending on checked statuses of that checkboxes? ( i mean if one of checkbox1 and checkbox2 clicked but only checkbox1 is checked do task1 and do task2 if both?)

You can assign one function to "onclick" of both checkboxes and write simple logic in it:
    if (getElementById("checkbox1").checked && !getElementById("checkbox2").checked) {
        alert("first");
    } else if (getElementById("checkbox1").checked && getElementById("checkbox2").checked) {
        alert("both");
    }